# How to throw and handle an error in swift?

Tags: swift

here is my code (Swift):

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class PlaySoundViewController: UIViewController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   if var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("movie_quote",ofType: "mp3"){
      var filePathUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)
      AVAUdioPlayer audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:filePathUrl) throws
   }
   else{
      print("filePath is empty")
   }
}
@IBAction func playSlowAudio(sender: UIButton) {
}
func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
   super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }
}
```

this is the method I found on my "Documentation and API References" to play audio: 
``

```
initWithContentsOfURL:error:
init(contentsOfURL url: NSURL) throws
```

So, I return a String as source path, then conver it to NSURL. Now i want to play the audio but the method I am using needs to throw the error and handle it. How should I throw and handle the error ?

Answer (score 3):

## Swift 2.0

`AVAudioPlayer` will throw an exception if its initializer fails. Catch the error by wrapping its initialization in a `do`/`catch` clause.

```
do {
    let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathUrl)
    // use audioPlayer
} catch {
    // handle error
}
```

As you can see, the keyword `try` is inserted before any method call that can throw exceptions. As long as the `try` statement doesn't `throw`, you can continue your code as normal. If the `try` statement does `throw`, you program will jump to the `catch` clause.

#### Examining the error

If you'd like to examine the error, you can convert it to an `NSError` by writing your `catch` statement like so (as seen in [Apple's Objective-C/Swift Interoperability Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID10)):

```
do {
    let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathUrl)
    // use audioPlayer
} catch let error as NSError {
    // error is now an NSError instance; do what you will
}
```

Converting to `NSError` is only necessary if you want to examine an error thrown by one of Apple's Cocoa objects. Native Swift code, throwing native `ErrorType` errors, require no conversion.

I recommend you read Apple's [new docs on error handling in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508).

---

## Swift 1.2

If you are using Swift 1.2, then there is no error handling available. Instead, `AVAudioPlayer`'s initialization method will fail and return `nil`.

If you are using Swift 1.2, I would recommend initializing the audio player like this:

```
var initError: NSError?
if let audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathUrl, error: &initError) {
    // use audioPlayer
} else {
    println(initError) // handle error
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to actually catch what the error is in Swift 2?

Comment: @devios Yes. Check out [Error Handling in Apple's Interop Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID10) if you are working with one of Apple's APIs, which shows how to convert the thrown exception into an NSError. Or [the Swift docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508) if your own Swift code will be throwing errors, in which case NSError is not needed

Answer (score 0):

Since Swift 1.2, you cannot throw/handle exceptions. While it is available in swift2 (need XCode7 support) which is still in beta. See this article for detail (https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-error-handling-try-catch).